# Should webpack have `webpack://` urls in production builds with source maps?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I know you shouldn't really have them in production anyway, and in the past I've only noticed `webpack://` being seen in my dev builds using `webpack-dev-server` and didn't know what's expected in prod builds.

Should webpack have `webpack://` urls if you have a production build with sourcemaps?

For instance if i look at my development builds sourcemap at something like `build/bundle.js.map` I see `webpack://` to map to my file location with `webpack-dev-server` to do quicker reloads (and I'm sure more) in dev mode and just wondering what's expected for production builds?

EDIT: I'm and idiot and was saying `sitemap` when I meant `sourcemap`

Comment: Yes, it's only in case of `webpack-dev-server` you shouldn't need it in production build.

Comment: will it have the `webpack://` for prod builds with them though?

Comment: but surely they are called sourcemaps

Comment: I know you already mentioned it, but why on earth would you want sitemaps for a production build? Don't they add a not insignificant amount of weight on the page?

Comment: I’d rather not mention the reason behind my questions as I’ve never seen this senario before but you’re correct I don’t want source maps in prod builds.

Answer (score 2):

The original question jumps around a bit, so I'll try to answer the question as I see it:

> Will source maps for "production" builds using webpack still have `webpack://`-style paths for source paths?

First and foremost, there *really* isn't such thing as a "production" build when it comes to the internals of webpack. In fact, there are 0 references to `NODE_ENV` in the actual source code of webpack.

This is important to point out because it paves the way to understanding that *webpack doesn't know about the environment it's building for*—you do. Thus, webpack's bundling output doesn't change unless you make it change, i.e. by changing the configuration webpack uses.

Moving on to source maps, all [devtools](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) (types source maps) use approximately the same (*configurable*) [devtool filename template](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-devtoolmodulefilenametemplate). All filenames used by devtools (source maps) follow that template, which defaults to starting with `webpack://`. Thus, all paths generated for source maps will start with `webpack://` given the default value.

So, to answer the above question: **yes**, source maps of "production" builds will have paths using the `webpack://` protocol unless the [`output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-devtoolmodulefilenametemplate) option is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in package.json file

```
     "scripts":{
        "start" : "webapck"
      }
```

after you get bundle.js or any other files. After you add in your .js files into the html file. And then to run your html page in any other environment like nodeJs...